# ffmpeg - how to create 5 second video zooming out effect with 1 image

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I know how to make 5 second video "zooming in" effect with 1 image using zoompan.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image1.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':d=125" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -s "800x450" zoomin.mp4
```

How do I do the "zooming out" video?

tried below but none of them are working:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image1.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='min(zoom-0.0015,1.5)':d=125" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -s "800x450" zoomout.mp4

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image1.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='max(1.5,zoom-0.0015)':d=125" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -s "800x450" zoomout.mp4

ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image_1.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='max(zoom-0.0015,1.5)':d=125" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -s "800x450" zoomin.mp4
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must first set the zoom factor, as by default it is set to 1.0. I was able to do so like this:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image_1.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.5,max(1.001,zoom-0.0015))':d=125" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -s "800x450" zoomout.mp4
```

Which will start zoomed in at 1.5 and zoom out 0.0015 every iteration. Note the value 1.001 was used (any value larger than 1.0) to ensure it would not zoom out past 1.0 and reset to 1.5.

Another solution could have been to simply reverse the output of your original zoompan, but after a quick search into it, reversing video seems like a lot of effort in ffmpeg.

Comment: How can we support this for multiple concatenated images? I thought d=125 will work but there is some problem as image tends to remain there for longer than 5 sec

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the z from the frame index (on) and the duration.

`on/duration` will get you a percent from 0-1 that grows each frame.

`1.5-on/duration*0.5` Gives you a number from 1.5-1.

All together:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image1.jpg -vf "zoompan=z='1.5-on/duration*0.5':d=125" -c:v libx264 -t 5 -s "800x450" zoomin.mp4
```